# insert 20 objects ion array

Tags: iphone

i need to hv an array of 20 objects.

initially array will hv 0 objects.
i hv add objbects 1 by 1,till it gets filled with 20 objects.
As soon as array gets 20 objects,and i try to insert a new object(for ex 21st object)

it should delete the 20th object and add itself to first position.

i hope i m giving u a clear picture,about wat i am looking for.

hope for a quick reply

regards
shishir

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you could start your sentences with uppercase-letters, and use real words like `have` and `you` instead of `hv` and `u`...

Comment: Yes, use English words and form sentences.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own class that uses an `NSMutableArray` for storage. When adding an item, first check whether there are already 20 objects in the array. If there are, remove the last object from the array. Then add the new object at the front.

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
{
    if ([dataArray count] == 20) {
        [dataArray removeLastObject];
    }
    [dataArray insertObject:anObject atIndex:0];
}
```

The above will always add the newest object at the front of the array. I guess that is what you want.

Comment: but how to add array index wise,my array is getting overwrite?
i am inserting object like this


appdelegate.completeToArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[appdelegate.completeToArray addObject:inSender];


this always overrights the previous value.
regards
shishir